# Incompatible parquet type in Impala

Tags: hive, schema, parquet, cloudera, impala

I have seen some other posts about this, but have not found an answer that permanently works.

We have a table, and I had to add two columns to it. In order to do so, I dropped the table and recreated it. But since it was an external table, it did not drop the associated data files. The data gets loaded from a control file and is partitioned by date. So let's say the dates that were in the table were `2021-01-01` and `2021-01-02`. But only `2021-01-02` is in the control file. So when I am loading that date, it gets re-run with the new columns and everything is fine. But `2021-01-01` is still there, but with a different schema.

This is no issue in Hive, as it seems to default to resolve by name, not position. But Impala resolves by position, so the new columns throw it off.

If I have a table that before had the columns `c1`,`c2`,`c3`, and now have the additional columns `c4`,`c5`, if I try to run a query such as

`select * from my_table where c5 is null limit 3;`

This will give an incompatible parquet schema error in Impala (but Hive is fine, it would just have `null` for `c4` and `c5` for the date `2021-01-01`).

If I run the command `set PARQUET_FALLBACK_SCHEMA_RESOLUTION=name;` and then the above query again, it is fine. But I would have to run `set PARQUET_FALLBACK_SCHEMA_RESOLUTION=name;` at the beginning of each session, which is not ideal.

From searching online, I have come up with a few solutions:

1. Drop all data files when creating the new table and just start loading from scratch (I think we want to keep the old files)
2. Re-load each date (this might not be ideal as there could be many, many dates that would have to be re-loaded and overwritten)
3. Change the setting permanently in Cloudera Manager (I do not have access to CM and don't know how feasible it would be to change it)

Are there any other solutions to have it so I don't have to run `set PARQUET_FALLBACK_SCHEMA_RESOLUTION=name;` each time I want to use this table in Impala?